How to attach common properties to messages produced via camel producer template
I want to set some common header/properties in the message produced via camel ProducerTemplate. This is useful when we want to attach some common properties to all outgoing messages.
For example, to send a message with a header we can write the following
template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:route", "Hello World", "X-Common-Header", "demo-value");

But, it would be great if we can do something like
// This line of code would be present wherever the producer template bean is being created/initialized
template.attachInterceptor((exchange) -> exchange.getIn().setHeader("X-Common-Header", "demo-value"));

// This line of code could be anywhere wherever we are producing messages
template.sendBody("direct:route", "Hello World");

For incoming messages, there is already RouteConfiguration which does this job well.

You could use the Exchange exchange = ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(context).withBody(body).withHeader("Header1", "value1").withHeader("Header2", "value2").build(); and then send this via template.send("direct:route", exchange);. Then you can always send an exchange, so this line will be the same, but you can build the exchange like you want.

@Raphi1I guess it can work, but it will require me to use same exchange creation logic which the sendBodyAndHeader is using.
It will expose some bits out, so its not the most elegant way, but it can work.
Exchange exchange = pattern != null ? endpoint.createExchange(pattern) : endpoint.createExchange();
Also 2 more lines to create these endpoint and pattern objects.
